# CakePHP: Data not saving in multiple tables

Tags: php, cakephp

Hey guys i am new to CakePHP so please help me in this,i am unable to save the single form data in two tables.Here is my code.

**Main model code:**

```
var $hasMany = array('Option');
```

**Controller code:**

```
public function add()
{
    if (!empty($this->request->data))
    {
       $this->Question->saveAll($this->data);
    }
}
```

**View file:**

```
echo $this->Form->create('Question');
echo $this->Form->input('question');
foreach (range(0,2) as $index) {
  echo $this->Form->input('Option.'.$index.'.option');
}
echo $this->Form->end('Save Poll');
```

Please tell me where i am going wrong. The data is inserting only in single table and not in other table.

Comment: pr($this->data) has Option fields?

Comment: yes..the array contains option field..

Answer (score 0):

Try this if its work.

```
<?php

if ($this->Question->save($this->data))
{
    $this->Question->Option->saveAll($this->data['Option']);
    $this->Session->setFlash(__('Question has been successfully edited.', true), 'default',array('class'=>'alert alert-success'));
    $this->redirect(array
    (
        'controller' => 'questions',
        'action'     => 'index'
    ));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: it is showing error...
Error: Call to a member function saveAll() on a non-object ...

Comment: does question and option model are not related to each other..???
question must be related using has Many and option must be related using belongs-to