# How to insert multiple entrys

Tags: cakephp

iam new to cake and want to set up a order process where the user could send some recommendations (friends mail adr) to get a discount. each recommendation reduces the price. so i want to have up to 5 recommendation inserts in one step.

recommendation table is like (id, order_id, email)

i extend the order model with recommendations

```
class Order extends AppModel {
    public $hasMany = array(
        'Recommendation' => array(
        'className' => 'Recommendation',
    )
);
```

in the order controller i have to use the saveall method.

now, how should the order add view look like. if i use

```
echo $this->Form->input('Recommendation.mail');
```

it will only save one recommendation, or ? But i would like to have up to 5 of them on one page...

Thank you very much,
Julius

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14516819/cakephp-data-not-saving-in-multiple-tables/14518476#14518476

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15088608/update-multiple-model-through-a-single-form/15089414#15089414

Answer (score 0):

Change your form to this

```
echo $this->Form->input('Recommendation.0.mail');
echo $this->Form->input('Recommendation.1.mail');
echo $this->Form->input('Recommendation.2.mail');
echo $this->Form->input('Recommendation.3.mail');
echo $this->Form->input('Recommendation.4.mail');
```

Then in your controller,use the saveAll method

```
$this->Recommendation->saveAll($this->request->data);
```